# How does an op amp reach equilibrium?

Tags: operational-amplifier, negative-feedback

It seems to me that if you try to solve for an Op-amps output (with negative feedback) discretely (i.e. iterating), you never reach equilibrium. Rather, you find the output moves further and further away from the desired value.

This leads me to believe that the output of an Op-amp does not "snap" to any value, but rather continuously rises or descends (albeit extremely quickly), so it passes it's point of stability and reaches equilibrium. Not sure if I've explained this well, but is this along the right lines?

Comment: What do you mean by point of stability?

Comment: Like a water lever control valve.  As the level rises it reduces the water flow until the desired level is reached.  Modern valves have hysteresis so that they do not hiss and wear out the valve seats like a Schmidt Trigger circuit in electronics.

Comment: @KalleMP, is this consistent with what I wrote? It seems that it is the high gain that is driving the output in the right direction.

Comment: The error value goes to zero when it is at equilibrium.  If the error goes negative (not possible in the water valve analogy) it will start to reverse the output drive and approach the desired point from the other direction.  It it cannot find the right point it will hunt/oscillate for a settling interval.

Comment: Why does nobody mention negative feedback? THIS is the keyword.

Comment: negative feedback is assumed and mentioned in the question.

Comment: Mr @19172281  **the issue is not that you never reach equilibrium but you never reach absolute zero error** with DC feedback.  Speed is defined by slew rate and settling time which is inverse to bandwidth,   But when the loop gain is much higher than your tolerance to error i.e. 1% or 0.001% we can say the loop gain error can be ignored and the Op Amp input is a virtual 0V input or virtual ground ( which by definition is 0V relative to some reference)  When the error becomes significant, we refer to input offset in the datasheet due to input bias & diff. in source impedances voltage drop etc.

Comment: Do you understand yet?

Comment: @TonyEErocketscientist, I understand that you never reach absolute zero error. When I refer to reaching equilibrium, I mean the point at which the difference between the two inputs multiplied by the Op amp's gain, causes the Op amp's output to "settle".

Comment: @TonyEErocketscientist, if changes to the output were instant, I can't see how we could reach this point as the outputs would saturate instantly, and you'd end up oscillating between the + and - rails.

Comment: If you could provide a graph or trace, it might simplify things. Thanks.

Comment: OP Amp theory kind of presupposes negative feedback.  They are not required to be ideal, have infinite gain or slew-rate or perfect linearity or other such ideal specifications.  However with the application of negative feedback they are able to correct for most of the errors, in essence ignoring the error terms by dividing them by the gain.  We accept the negative feedback, without it you are talking about a Comparator that has (similar) specifications that cause it to slew fast on the out put for small input changes.  They are similar enough that many can cross dress just not so well.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for the lengthy answer:

To answer your question it helps to analyze what may happen after switch-on the power supplies +/- Vs=+/-10V. More than that, you have to apply negative feedback (resistive netork between output node and inverting input).
(The described timely sequence may be somewhat „formalistic“ - however, it helps to understand the feedback concept).

**Example**: Non-inverting gain stage with desired gain of "+2". That means: Feedback factor k=0.5 using a voltage divider with two equal resistors 
Open-loop gain (assumption): Aol=1E4.

1.) t=0: Apply at  an input voltage Vin=1V. The opamp is not yet working in its linear range (feedback not yet active due to time constants within the circuit) and the output will immediately jump to Vs=+10V.

2.) t>0: The voltage at the inverting terminal will rise to 0.5Vs=5V>Vin=1V. Hence, the voltage at this inverting terminal dominates (is larger) and the output voltage will change in the direction to minus 10V.

3.) However, on its way to -10V the ouput voltage is crossing a positive value which produces at the inverting terminal a feedback voltage of +0.99980004V .

4.) At this very moment (assuming an open-loop gain Aol=1E4) , the opamp is in its linear amplification region because the diff. voltage is Vdiff=Vin-0.99980004=1-0.99980004=0.00019996V.
As a result, the output voltage is Vout=Vdiff*Aol=0.00019996*1E4=1.9996001V.

5.) This is a stable **equilibrium** because: the classical feedback formula for a finite value of Aol also gives  the output voltage Vout=Vin*[1E4/(1+0.5E4)]=1.9996001 V.

6.) That means: We have an equilibrium because the output voltage has a value which exactly meets the condition Vout=Vdiff*Aol.
Any larger/smaller output voltage causes a small reduction/increase for Vdiff thereby correcting this deviation from the equilibrium.

7.) In this example, the input difference voltage, of course, is NOT zero. It never will be zero - however, the diff. voltage is so small (in our case app. 0.2mV) that in can be neglected (assumed to be zero for calculations) in many cases.

Comment: 100 yr old control theory agrees with the P in a  PID controller continuously calculates an error value as the difference between the input and scaled feedback output based on proportional, integral, and derivative terms and the open loop gain. PID is Proportional-Integral-Derivative, referring to the three terms operating on the error signal to produce a control signal.  Thus input P error is inversely proportional to loop gain.  If you study control Theory, this answer will become self-evident.

Comment: Well, I had the impression that the questioner is not very familiar with control theory - so I gave him a step-by-step explanation. Anything wrong with my answer? Or - what is the background of your comment? I do not understand. I am not sure, if a newbie would be satisfied with the answer ..."P error is inversely proportional to loop gain".

Comment: So - it seems that you do not like my answer. I am very sorry about that. However, perhaps it helps the questioner (and some other newbies) better to understand the process of equilibrium search.

Comment: @LvW, "However, on its way to -10V the ouput voltage is crossing a positive value which produces at the inverting terminal a feedback voltage of +0.99980004V " - This appears to confirm what I thought - that the outputs do not change instantly. You need the output to linearly change so that it "find" the value which settles the output.

Comment: @LvW, I do not see what PID has to do with this?

Comment: @19172281...I am with you. It was not me who has brought this term into the discussion (see the first comment).

Answer (score 1):

Nope, not even close.

Think of the inputs as an error signal that is always 0V with negative feedback because the extremely high gain forces the output to offset the input to create that zero differential voltage or "virtual ground", as it is called.

That converges to zero Voltage error (plus some tiny Input offset spec.) according to the rise time t=0.35/f  where f = GBW (Gain BandWidth) / Gain . That rise time is also the function of the load capacitance from its current limit for an abrupt step input voltage, which must be considered in [pF] at some V/us slew rate where dV/dt = Imax/C

### more info

There is internal slew rate limiting to create this Gain Bandwidth product which also reduces the multi-stage transistor frequency RC cascades from a high order circuit to a simple 1st low pass filter like a gain of 1 million at 10 Hz and then an open loop gain of 1 at 10Mhz for GBW=10Mhz

### Why

This is measured by phase margin ( or unity gain phase error) and there is often a need to give slightly more bandwidth or a tendency towards offering slightly more gain while compromise 90 deg phase margin down to 60 degrees or less with a 2nd order system that has some overshoot.

Thus the unity gain phase margin spec is used to determine the amount of overshoot or from actual datasheet specs.  A true 1st order loop never has overshoot but then it will be slightly slower to respond.  A low gain amp will respond quickest and a high gain slowest due to this internal compensation cap that makes it more stable from overshoot.

But regardless the input error is amplified that it always converges rapidly to zero unless you add "positive feedback" then it diverges like a Schmitt Trigger or comparator with hysteresis.

### added

To show how a typical Op Amp responds to a large step input voltage with slew rate limiting and small step input with a capacitive load that reduces phase margin which in turn produces overshoot.

Note the large signal step response is 10us due to current limit and on the right a small step response with a C load has a slew time of t=0.35/GBW  where GBW=1MHz  and the step down from 1 to 1.35 us or a slew time of 0.35us is correct. But the settling time is about 3 cycles at 1MHz ( the BW @ unity gain) or 3 us which is also consistent.

**In both cases, the convergence or settling error with a unity (x1) gain and open loop gain of 10^6 is 1uV per Volt input.**  Why ? Because GBW= 1e6 ( 1MHz), gain, Av  = 1 so Error=1/GBW*Av =1e-6

If Gain was 1K then the error would be increased to 1e-3  or 0.1%

which is close enuf to zero for government work... ;)

[image]

Comment: This seems similar to how I have it worked out in my mind The high gain pushes the output in the right direction where it inevitably reached a stable point.

Comment: I must admit that I do not understand why the finite GBW and phase margin considerations (and even the limited slew rate) should have to do something with the question of a stable DC bias point. To me, the keyword for the whole problem is "negative feedback". In principle, there is no difference to the classical method of fixing (stabilizing) the DC bias point of a simple transistor stage. Therefore, I am really surprised that the term "negative feedback" is not mentioned in the above answer.

Comment: @19172281...Therefore, the last sentence in your comment is not correct. The high gain has nothing to do with reaching an equilibrium. This would happen also for gain blocks with an open-loop gain of 1E3 or 1E2 (transistor example). Without negative feedback no real opamp would reach a stable equilibrium.

Comment: @LvW the condition was stated in the question, that's why. "(with negative feedback)"  thus the convergence error is always 1/GH for resistive feedback which is pretty close to zero.

Comment: Tony...as far as I have understood the question, the problem was not if the convergence error is small or lange - but: IF and WHY we will have convergence (equilibrium). This I have tried to answer in my contribution (which you do not like). And I really don`t know why in this context you have mentioned GBW, slew rate and phase margin.

Comment: @LvW it was to hopefully clear up the OP's confusion of "Snap" vs  "rises or descends"  These  factors must be learnt to clear this confusion.  On your answer the example has many significant figures but then neither of us focused on basic Control Theory which simplifies it even better for net error=1/G(s)H(s)

Comment: @Tony...if you read again the first sentence of the original question you will notice that the questioner has tried to "discretely (iterating)" find an equilibrium - however, without success. Do you agree that my contribution was an attempt to exactly answer THIS problem? (Without using control theory, PID-controllers, GBW, phase margin etc....)? What is your problem with my answer???

Comment: @LvW dont take my comment personally. I dont object to your answer. Just that Control Theory is the general solution.  THe   loop gain reduces the input error towards zero.  ( which as we know loop gain is the product of forward open loop gain times the reverse or feedback attenuation). around the loop.

Comment: Tony...just for information: I am familiar with these terms. I have published a book on Control Theory, Active Filters and Oscillators (in German).

Comment: I  have no doubt you know.

Answer (score 0):

How close to "zero" will that opamp settle? The zero is limited by VDD noise and internal opamp noise. Lets compute/estimate the internal opamp noise.

Assume Rnoise in the opamp is 1Kohm, flat DC to some high frequency. That produces 4 nanoVoltsRMS per Hertz of bandwidth. These random bits of energy come from the electrons flailing around in the resistors and transistor channels and transistor junctions.

Assume the bandwidth is 1MegaHertz. This produces 1,000,000 frequency bins, which we combine by RSS the 1,000,000 bins.
A simpler way to scale the 4nanoVoltsRMS by sqrt(frequency interval) or 4nV * sqrt(1,000,000) or 4nV * 1,000.

Thus the input-referred noise is 4nV * 1,000 or 4 microVolts.

Your "zero" is really 4 microVoltsRMS.